# Need clarification in SQLCmd.exe

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Have a Sql Script file name spCreation.sql with the following contents.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_select_customers
 as
 Begin
    SELECT EMP.NAME, EMP.ID FROM analysis.customerDB.dbo.employeetbl
 END
```

Open this file and execute on Queryanalyser, without creating a Linked Server "Analysis" it is not throughing any error and query executed successfully.

Execute the same sql file through sqlcmd like follows on command prompt.

sqlcmd -s [Server] [Database] [Login] [Password] spCreation.sql

it is throwing an exception for the notify server. 
Can any one explain how sqlCmd execution behaviour and query analyser execution behaviour?

Error message follows

**Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Server VIJAY-PC, Procedure usp_select_customers, Line 4 Could not find server 'analysis' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserv er to add the server to sys.servers.**

Comment: Please post the error number and message you get, don't have to make it a mystery novel for us to guess...

Comment: Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Server VIJAY-PC, Procedure usp_select_customers,
 Line 4
Could not find server 'analysis' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server
 name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserv
er to add the server to sys.servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the query in SSMS gives the very same error:

> Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Procedure usp_select_customers, Line 4
>   Could not find server 'analysis' in sys.servers. Verify that the
>   correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored
>   procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

So the problem is not the difference between sqlcmd or SSMS, it must be something else. For instance you're running against a different machine, or you simply don't run it in SSMS but simply check the syntax.

Comment: Yes now it showing the same exception on SSMS also. Earlier I deleted the linked server and executed the procedure in the same Query analyser window. Now I closed the previouse instance and open a new instance execute the same query it throwing the exception.